# While (true) loop in a Task silently exits

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, infinite-loop

I made a chat bot application that goes through all received messages and responds to them with a specified interval (~1 second). The code portion responsible looks like this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork());

void DoWork()
{
    try {
        while (true) 
        {
            ProcessMessages();
            Thread.Sleep(sleepInterval);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {Log(ex + "");}
}
```

The problem is this loop sometimes exits without showing any messages or without an exception getting thrown and logged. I read somewhere that `Thread.Sleep()` may be the problem because the system might think the task is unresponsive and try to terminate it, so it should be changed to an `EventWaitHandle` and do `waitHandle.WaitOne(sleepInterval)` instead, but it didn't help me.

I'm running the app on debug and when I see the app is not doing the work,  I set a break point inside the loop and visual studio doesn't pause. The timers inside the processing task show that they weren't updated for some time. The "infinite" loop just dies silently.

It's a winforms app and I've noticed that sometimes they don't break automatically when run in debug mode, even if an exception is thrown. But I only know this happens when an exception originates somewhere in the code called by one of the controls' methods. This is a `Task` however, so I don't know if it should work in the same way.

The code inside the processing method may be throwing exceptions, but then why don't they get logged even though the call is within a try-catch clause? What could make the loop end suddenly? How can I make my app more reliable?

Comment: It's almost always the case that if you use `Thread.Sleep` you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: If it's a WinForms app, isn't it simpler to use a timer and run `ProcessMessages` every time it ticks instead of making a `Task`? Or even better, make it event driven and respond to the messages in realtie.

Comment: You should also take out the `catch(Exception ex)` and see if you get a meaningful error pop up somewhere. General purpose catches are a bad thing.

Comment: It's some time since i wrote C#, but is it possible the Exceptions ToString method returns an empty String ?
This is the case if the inner Message object is null, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.exception.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Enigmativity: `Thread.Sleep` doesn't always mean you're doing something wrong. Sometimes you need to do this to avoid overtaxing the CPU. Example: a "forever" loop listening in on a socket.

Comment: @code4life - "Wrong" might not be the best word, but there's generally a better way to do it than `Thread.Sleep` though.

Comment: @Enigmativity: probably in a UI app. But `Thread.Sleep` is a canonically accepted approach for those darned spin locks that are CPU intensive.

Comment: @code4life, there's `Thread.SpinWait` to address those darned spin locks.

Comment: @user1306322, you should be using `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` (and you wouldn't need `Task.Factory.StartNew` then). But that doesn't answer the question, so what is the signature of `ProcessMessages` method? Are you using `async void` methods anywhere?

Comment: @Noseratio: not 100% identical functionality, since `Thread.Sleep` always forces the thread to yield processor time (thus giving the poor CPU some badly needed oxygen). `Thread.SpinWait` may under certain circumstances not do that, since it`will` spin (which is why its called a spinwait, lol), thus potentially running up clock cycles on the CPU.

Answer (score 2):

I don't trust `Thread.Sleep` inside infinite loops and inside tasks. You should use a proper timer at least.

To do this kind of thing I would use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (known as "Rx").

Here's the code:

```
var subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
        .Subscribe(n =>
        {
            ProcessMessages();
        });
```

Basically it sets up a timer to process your messages.

When you want it to stop just do `subscription.Dispose()`.

You can NuGet "Rx-Main" to get the bits.

Comment: Because you forcefully make your thread instead of having a timer which would run in parallel without causing any issues

Comment: @user1306322 - `Thread.Sleep` isn't a timer. It's more like a time machine.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I dunno, starting `Timer`s in unknown numbers of background threads always makes me paranoid, since a `Timer` eats up some very real OS resources.

Comment: @code4life - Rx manages timers very efficiently. I believe you end up with only one per scheduler.

Comment: @Enigmativity: not sure what the value-add is if bg threads have to share resources - in this case the one-timer-per-scheduler bottleneck. Would mean some threads are just sitting around before they can get serviced by the timer, no? Also the timer-to-thread communication implies a thread jump since each live in their own thread, which may not be a desired consequence. I dunno, still not convinced timers are the best way to go. Lots of small but critical issues getting swept under the rug by using timer. Feels like using a sledgehammer for a small nail. Effective, but sometimes overkill, IMHO.

Comment: @code4life - "Would mean some threads are just sitting around before they can get serviced by the timer, no?" - No. The schedulers use a priority heap to ensure all events are fired in a timely manner.